# What are the the different crew member bonuses?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I picked up a crew member of an alien race at a store (I hope he was for hire and not an alien slave...) and I noticed that they had slightly modified stats from humans. Vivimord is an Engi and he has double repair speed and half combat damage.

Do other races have different stats? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this page](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Races):

Humans comprise the majority of both the Galactic Federation and the Rebel Fleet. Humans learn skills faster due to their reduced XP ability, have no notable weaknesses and are the cheapest race to hire from Stores.

- Skills improve slightly faster (10%)

Engi originate from the Engi Homeworld. They take 50  to hire, with the following special traits:

- Repair speed is doubled
- Combat damage is halved

The Mantis originate from the Mantis Homeworld. It takes 45  to hire them.

- Inflict 1.5x damage in combat
- 1.2x move speed
- Halved repair speed

Rockmen are strong creatures and take 65  to hire. Their abilites are:

- Immune to fire
- Movement speed is halved
- Health is increased to 150%

Zoltan usually appear in Engi Homeworlds or Engi-Controlled Worlds. They appear rarely, and it takes 65  to hire them. Their special abilities are:

- Provides (1) power to occupied system
- Health is 70
- Explode when killed, damaging all enemy crew in the room

Slugs are one of the rarest crew to find. Their advantage is the ability to see your enemy's crew, and to be able to see the rooms surrounding the slug in your ship if your sensor goes down. They cost 45  to hire.

- Telepathic powers reveal rooms and lifeforms even when sensors are down.

The Lanius are scavengers – metallic lifeforms that rely on the absorption of minerals to sustain themselves. They are available only in advanced edition and even then are almost exclusively found in the Abandoned Sector where they cost 50 to hire. They need no oxygen and also drain oxygen from the room they are in.

- Drains oxygen from rooms
- -20% movement speed
- No damage from suffocation

And a final 'secret' race:

> Crystals can be found in Life support pods that are revived by scientists. Doing so also begins a special quest to the Rock Homeworlds.
>
>  - Lockdown power: When finished charging, sends crystals to surround the room they are in, making it completly invincible to damage (Only that specific room). Nothing can exit/enter the specific room until the ability wears off.
>  - Reduced suffocation damage
>  - Movement speed -20%
>  - Health 125

Comment: I've also observed personally that humans tend to learn faster at their stations while engis level up super slow at combat (since they don't do much damage they kill slower?), but it could just be the particular way I play through the game at that point

Comment: So sending a crystal with a boarding party would be cool, because it could lock the room off, but would suck, because you couldn't actually damage the system. Hrm. Seems like you need to send them to lockdown the chokepoints!

Comment: @Sterno using him to lock people out of medbays so I can kill them is what I do with him

Comment: Mantis damage is x1.5 (+50% damage), not double.

Comment: @SysDragon Updated for Advanced Edition.

Answer (score 1):

With advanced edition you have a new race; [Lanius](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Lanius#Lanius) appear in Abandoned Sector, available to hire them at stores from 50 scrap:

- Drains oxygen from occupied room
- No damage from lack of oxygen
- Movement speed -20%